# rails scope without associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, scope

I  have a model called "activos", I need to show only the records that are not associated with another model called "relactivo".

I've been trying this in the model:   scope :ts, -> { includes(:relactivo).where(relactivo: { activo: nil}) }

this is my model "activos"

```
class Activo < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "IdActivos"

  scope :ts, -> { includes(:relactivo).where(relactivo: { activo: nil}) }


  has_one :relactivo, class_name: "Relactivo", foreign_key: "Activo"


end
```

and my model "relactivo"

```
class Relactivo < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "IdRow"
  belongs_to :activo, class_name:"Activo", foreign_key: "Activo"

end
```

Comment: Hi - so what is the error that you are seeing with the code you have? What do you expect instead?

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this for your scope:

```
class Activo < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "IdActivos"

    scope :ts, -> { joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN relactivos ON relactivos.IdActivos = activos.IdActivos WHERE relactivos.IdActivos IS null'))) }

    has_one :relactivo, class_name: "Relactivo", foreign_key: "IdActivos"

  end
```

See if this works, The custom primary/foreign key makes it a little strange but try this.

Comment: Isn't `left_outer_joins` new in Rails5?

Comment: @muistooshort, you are absolutely right. I'll update my answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @DanRubio thanks but still showing me all the records

Comment: Ok, I think you're problem might be your foreign_key in `Relactivo` and 'Activo'. You are telling `Relactivo`that it belongs to `Activo` and to be linked to it with the foreign key of `Activo`, but in `Activo` you are saying that the primary key is `IdActivos` so it should be `IdActivo` for both the has_one and belongs_to

Comment: I updated my answer to modify the OUTER JOIN sql. That should get what you are looking for.